# Cooking corned beef brisket for maximum slice-ability

Tags: corned-beef

I want to prepare a nice corned beef meal, but I don't know the best way to do it.  Last year I did it in a crock pot.  It was delicious, but the brisket feel apart so much that the presentation was very lacking.  I was unable to slice against the grain (probably had something to do with the subpar knife I was using, but still).  I want good looking even slices of beef, so how should I cook the roast?

Comment: I found a nice related question here by browsing the tag: http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/8773/how-do-you-keep-corned-beef-from-falling-apart-in-the-crockpot

Answer (score 6):

After your brisket is cooked, refrigerate it overnight. This will help it stay solid when you slice it, and will also improve the texture and flavor. Reheat it before serving. If you have time, this will improve many slow cooked foods.

Comment: Good idea.  I am wondering, will this compromise the moistness of the meat?

Comment: Not if you wrap it tightly in plastic wrap.

Comment: I would say skip the plastic wrap. Cool it in the container you cooked it in, with the liquid. The act of the meat cooling without it being cut will make the meat moister than if it was eaten immediately. As the meat cools, it draws moisture in. This is why it is recommended that meat rest before serving.

Answer (score 1):

Once it's been brined for a week, I simmer my corned beef in just enough water to cover it, for about 2 1/2 hours, or until it's tender to the fork. I then leave it to cool for at least half an hour before slicing, though it cuts better when cold.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the recipe handy, but I have done a baked corned beef with an orange and spice glaze.  It came out tender but sliceable, just the right amount of chewiness, and was perfect for sandwiches the next day.  It was probably on allrecipes.com.

I would recommend the center cut for that.  Roast fat-side up, cut across the grain, etc.  I think the only thing the tips are good for is chopping up for hash.