# Corned Beef, Cabbage vs. Reuben - Multipurpose?

Tags: charcuterie, corned-beef

Good evening, all.  Quick, specific question here (something too esoteric for most cooking sites I checked):

I have ~2.25lb of Corned Beef Brisket (Point Cut)", fresh &  vacuum-sealed with spices and all that.  I bought it with the intention of making Reuben sandwiches (R's) for my waifu and I...  But then simultaneously bought a head of cabbage, thinking "Ah, Easter; corned beef & cabbage (CB&C)!"  Aaaaand they have sat in the fridge, since I cannot figure out if I can do both.

My lack of culinary initiative aside, I am trying to determine:

- Is the "Corned Beef" used in CB&C the same as used in R's?
- Is the above a matter of preparation (i.e. my plans to slow-cooker it would be perfect for CB&C but bad for R's?)
- If no to the above, *can* it be made so?

To further complicate things, I purchased a *can* of the very same substance ("Corned Beef"); is *that* useful for either CB&C, R's, or both (or neither; I'm not sure it's not just glorified SPAM)?

Anyway, thanks for reading my overly-complicated question.  Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Looking at some recipes for each, I would say different preparation. Which recipe(s) did you look at?

Answer (score 1):

Canned corned beef is sort of Spam, but with different meat and flavoring. It's also more like hash, and doesn't always cleanly slice the same way Spam does. I definitely wouldn't put it on a Reuben sandwich, but it could work with cabbage. (Not *great* with cabbage, but that's an opinion issue -- I'm not a big fan of canned meat in general.)

In contrast, a cooked **corned beef brisket can be used either in Reuben sandwiches or on a plate of corned beef & cabbage**. The only particular difference is the thickness of the slices. In a sandwich, one generally wants thin-sliced meat that is easier to bite through. Thicker slices work well next to cabbage, when eating the dish with a knife and fork.

Comment: Thanks for the response!

(Canned) - As it was prophecied.  I figured it wouldn't be ideal.  Still, I'm sure it'll taste fine fried with some eggs or hash or whatever.

(Brisket) - Ah, wonderful.  I can work out the slice issue, but I'm curious as to the answer to the 2nd question (sorry if unclear):  "In what way should I prepare the Brisket so as best to use it for both" (corollary:  "is there a "preferred" method of preparation for either recipe that would make it less usable for the alternative")?

Comment: Any corned beef brisket method should work -- your slow cooker plan, or simmering on the stovetop in a pot. This question might be a useful read: http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/13198/cooking-corned-beef-brisket-for-maximum-slice-ability

Comment: Just note that a Reuben is made with sauerkraut, which is cabbage, it's not something you are likely to make any time soon as sauerkraut is a fermented pickle. Buy a small bag of sauerkraut for your Reuben sandwich. :-)